# SFTP not saving the project

Tags: hosting, sftp

I am using hostinger and VSCode, I tried to use the sftp but it didn't save. After I save when I try to close and re-open the edited file it looks like it's not edited. Then I realized the error message in my terminal it's like that:

```
[03-20 21:03:19] [error] Error: Failure
    at 101 (c:\Users\yelda\.vscode\extensions\natizyskunk.sftp-1.16.1\node_modules\ssh2\lib\protocol\SFTP.js:2704:19)
    at SFTP.push (c:\Users\yelda\.vscode\extensions\natizyskunk.sftp-1.16.1\node_modules\ssh2\lib\protocol\SFTP.js:278:11)
    at CHANNEL_DATA (c:\Users\yelda\.vscode\extensions\natizyskunk.sftp-1.16.1\node_modules\ssh2\lib\client.js:525:23)
    at 94 (c:\Users\yelda\.vscode\extensions\natizyskunk.sftp-1.16.1\node_modules\ssh2\lib\protocol\handlers.misc.js:859:16)
    at Protocol.onPayload (c:\Users\yelda\.vscode\extensions\natizyskunk.sftp-1.16.1\node_modules\ssh2\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:2025:10)
    at AESGCMDecipherNative.decrypt (c:\Users\yelda\.vscode\extensions\natizyskunk.sftp-1.16.1\node_modules\ssh2\lib\protocol\crypto.js:987:26)
    at Protocol.parsePacket [as _parse] (c:\Users\yelda\.vscode\extensions\natizyskunk.sftp-1.16.1\node_modules\ssh2\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:1994:25)
    at Protocol.parse (c:\Users\yelda\.vscode\extensions\natizyskunk.sftp-1.16.1\node_modules\ssh2\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:293:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (c:\Users\yelda\.vscode\extensions\natizyskunk.sftp-1.16.1\node_modules\ssh2\lib\client.js:713:21)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:526:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) download c:\Users\yelda\Desktop\siteler\home\liftli65\public_html\index.html
```

I tried other sftp extensions but they didn't work as well. my SFTP code looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "huseyinyeldan.com",
    "host": "11.111.111.11",
    "port": 65002,
    "protocol": "sftp",
    "username": "*******",
    "password": "**********",
    "remotePath": "/home/********/public_html",
    "uploadOnSave": true
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

I tried to use the sftp so It saved my files but it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem with SFTP and VSCode. It turned out my disk quota was exceeded on the remote location. I freed some space and now it works